# PHP Special Character Parse Error

Tags: php, mysql, xml, unicode, encoding

I am parsing a XML and putting it into MySQL. Now MySQL is showing following error for some specific records inserting:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xEAm-Kh\xEA...'
```

When i check the data inside XML, it is showing like `iêm-Khê`
So the Special Character `ê` is transforming into `xEA`
What is it?

**How can i get it solved to maintain & put its original Character into Database?**

FYI, here is some info.:

- My whole MySQL DB itself is using `latin1_swedish_ci`
- But that TABLE & COLUMN are using `utf8_general_ci`
- ** When i manually Copy/Paste that `iêm-Khê` values into the MySQL Record directly, it is saved. (I mean, MySQL is accepting that Special Characters.) So i think the issue is at the Coding side.

Comment: Use UTF-8 charset to mysql DB:)

Comment: OMG!! I found `latin1_swedish_ci` is using on my DB @_@ Can i safely change it to `utf-8` ? Coz my DB is very large now and having important Records inside. Is it safe to change that easily?

Comment: Yea  we can use it , use sample db first using `alter` command  and test it, if you are gonna start it from creation you can follow the answers below to define the charset as default to your DB or for the table  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional research I ran across two possible approaches to a solution:

```
- the first option is to use php's utf8_encode() function.
- the second option uses some code with the PDO using set names (though there seemed to be some discussion as to whether or not this worked for everyone.

$handle = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname",
    'username', 'password', 
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

The following link had some other useful information:
[See here](http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: Ok i got it by using php `utf8_encode()` function. As in my edited question, it was not the DB issue. Thankss :))

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the character set of the database to `UTF-8`.

***Command:***

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

***For alter the column:***

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] MODIFY
[column_name] [data_type]
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: OMG!! I found `latin1_swedish_ci` is using on my DB @_@ Can i safely change it to `utf-8`? Coz my DB is very large now and having important Records inside. Is it `SAFE` to change that easily?

Comment: @4lvin　Do everything on a test db frist.

Comment: Actually i'm using Drupal. God dam* i've never known that Drupal default DB Encoding is using that Stup*d encode collation >.<

Comment: ** But when i check that TABLE ONLY, it is using `utf8_general_ci`. Does it mean something? or, Do i still need to change the WHOLE db charset?

Comment: @4lvin Check the column also.

Comment: Ya, the column also is `utf8_general_ci`. What should i do now? :(

Comment: @4lvin Is the character set `utf8`?

Comment: `Database Collation: latin1_swedish_ci` but `That Table's Collation: utf8_general_ci` and `Column Collation: utf8_general_ci` also.

Comment: @4lvin Not only the Collation, but you need to check the charset.

Comment: @_@ How can i set the Charset as there is only `Collation` setting inside MySQL (PhpMyAdmin)

Comment: FYI (i edited the question) When i manually Copy/Paste that `iêm-Khê` values into the MySQL Record directly, it is then saved. (I mean, MySQL is accepting that Special Characters.) So i think the issue is at the Coding side.

Comment: @4lvin If this is the problem, you should run `SET NAMES utf8` first.

Comment: @4lvin The alter command, but it seems the issue is in your coding side.

Comment: Ya, now i think it is coding problem. Can you suggest pls?

Comment: @4lvin Try `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');` after you create the connection.

Comment: What is `NAMES` pls? Exactly to run as it is?

Answer (score 0):

You should define the `UTF-8 charset` to the mysql DB, by `default` it used to be `latin charset` , we can define the `utf-8` along with `table definition` or on `database` creation,

To Table

```
 create table `my_table` (.....

  .... ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

To  database

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

correct me if 'm worng